# Propositional logical equivalence in Lemmon style proof

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I am doing a bit of propositional logic and I was wondering does Lemmon style of proofing allows writing logical equivalence of some propositions. There is an example of biconditional that you can express it using conjunction and conditional.
Example:

```
P, (P ↔ Q) ⊢ Q

1  (1)P                 Assumption
2  (2)P ↔ Q             Assumption
2  (3)(P → Q) & (Q → P) 2 Df. ↔
```

Is this possible with other logical expressions? If yes, what do you write on a right side where you write from where did you get this proposition and what rule did you apply. 
Possible example:

```
P, (P → Q) ⊢ Q   

1  (1)P                 Assumption
2  (2)P → Q             Assumption
2  (3)¬P V Q            2 (What to write here)
3  (4)¬(P & ¬Q)         3 (What to write here)
```

Comment: Do you have a link or reference to the particular system you are working with?

Comment: I am reading E.J. Lemmons book Beginning logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example seems to indicate that the $\leftrightarrow$ is *defined* as a conjunction of two conditionals.  That is, $\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ is seen as *shorthand* for $(\varphi \rightarrow \psi) \land (\psi \rightarrow \varphi)$

Some formal proof systems do indeed do this, and some will even consider the rewriting of that definition/shorthand as a step in the proof, which is what your example proof seems to be doing.

However, this is not the same as using any kind of logical equivalence to rewrite statements.  If you want to rewrite statements using logical equivalences, then the formal proof system needs to have the corresponding rules defined for that. If the system has not defined those equivalences as rules, then you are not allowed to do that within the system

OK, but maybe the proof system, has some other definitions/shorthands, like the one you propose for the $\rightarrow$, or for the $\lor$?  Well, that's possible, but again that all depends on how your proof system has defined its formal syntax, and its rules.

Comment: I am reading E.J. Lemmons book Beginning logic and I didn't find rules for my logical equivalences. I tought of them like it is the same if you write (P v Q) or you can write (Q v P). As long as truth tables are the same... why not.

Comment: @Slit Yeah, you'd think .. but unfortunately formal proofs don't work that way. The game there is: follow the rules!  If there's no rule for it, you can't do it, sorry!

Comment: Pity... Well maybe in some other system...

Comment: @Slit  Yes, there are formal proof systems that use all kinds of equivalence rules as inference rules.  Symbolic Logic by Copi comes to mind. Also Introduction to Logic by Copi and Cohen.  So again, not just *any* logical equivalence can be used, but at least they define some of the important ones, like Commutation, Association, Double Negation, Distribution, DeMorgan, Implication, and Equivalence

Comment: I will look up. I hope it is similar to Lemmon

Comment: Copi has the rules I need. Thanks!

Comment: @Slit Cool!  It's not a 'Lemmon-style' system though ....

Comment: Lemmon has it but it is indirect proof. And you have to put on a right from where did you get it. Page 38. Link: [https://books.google.hr/books?id=qkmG04_ecLMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=lemmon&hl=hr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjd7Iek5dfVAhVJDcAKHdNPCeoQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=36&f=false]

Comment: @Slit Thanks for the link ... I don't have the book.   I note that on p.40 he does indeed *define* the $\leftrightarrow$ as a shorthand for the conjunction of the two conditionals. But all other connectives are primitive connectives, so there are no other definitions.  And I do indeed not see any equivalence rules defined as inference rules. indeed, note how his proofs on p.38 are much longer than it would take if you had a couple of simple equivalence rules!

Comment: Check page 58. [https://books.google.hr/books?id=qkmG04_ecLMC&lpg=PP1&dq=lemmon&hl=hr&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q&f=true]

Comment: @Slit Oh, cool, so you can basically 'box up' any earlier proof, like a subroutine or Lemma, and refer to it in later proofs. My software prover allows that as well, but I haven't seen that too often actually defined as part of the theoretical system (in axiom systems it's pretty standard practice (check out metamath), but this is the first time I see it in a sequent system). Thanks!

Comment: i am also writting an app for logic proof :-). Can I see yours?

Comment: @Slit It's not one that I myself built, just one I use a lot: it's called Fitch and it comes with the textbook Language, Proof, and Logic.

Comment: How does Fitch system handles truthfulness in 1. order logic? Are there truth tables or truth threes? I prefer truth tables but apparently no system has truth tables for first order logic.

Comment: @Slit There is a good reason FOL does not have truth tables. Truth-tables are a way to exhaustively explore all possible kinds of worlds/situations.  For any kind of propositional logic statement or argument, there are only finitely many such kinds of worlds/situations, as there only only finitely many atomic propositions involved, and each of those is assumed to be either true or false. So with $n$ atomic propositions, the table has $2^n$ rows, corresponding to the $2^n$ possible types/kinds of worlds/situations. ... (Continued)

Comment: @Slit In FOL logic, however, there are always an infinite number of possible kinds of worlds to consider, as the number of objects in the domain of any type/kind of world can range from 1 to infinite.  And this makes a difference: for any $n$, you can generate a FOL statement that would be true only in a world with exactly $n$ objects ... meaning that if you want to exhaustively consider all worlds of all possible sizes, you need to consider infinitely many ... your 'truth-table' would have to be infinitely big.  Which of course means that T-tables are no longer a viable option for FOL.

Comment: @Slit  What you *can* do in FOL, however, is formal proofs.  Which is what Fitch does: it is an interface for the user to create and verify formal proofs. Truth-trees can also be extended for FOL ... unfortunately the software package does not have a piece of software that supports the creation and verification of truth-trees.  What it *does* have, though, is a piece of software called Tarski's World, which is actually quite interesting: in it, you can create worlds, create FOL sentences, and then evaluate the sentences in the worlds.  So that teaches you to 'read and write' FOL really well.

Comment: Can you put link to the resource for learning Fitch system?

Comment: @Slit Here is a link to the commercial book and software package I have been referring to: https://ggweb.gradegrinder.net/lpl  But there are many 'Fitch'-style proof systems.  Here is the Wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch_notation  for a basic overview. And here is an online page for constructing and verifying Fitch proofs that works much the same as the software from the commercial package: http://proofmood.com/en/Fitch/Doc/doc.html

Comment: Great! This is then more like Copi style

Comment: @Slit Yes, it will feel more like Copi than like Lemmon given the explicit 'subproof' structures.